# Hyperledger Fabric: membersrvc.yaml missing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the hyperledger docs (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/#running-the-validating-peer)

At the this point I stuck:

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
peer network login <username>

<username> is expected to be in membersrvc.yaml but it's missing: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/membersrvc/membersrvc.yaml

Further:
 
make membersrvc
gives this error:
make: *** No rule to make target 'membersrvc'.  Stop.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

At the point that you are, if you followed correct the docs you should have opened one terminal for *membersrvc*, one for *peer* and one for *CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02* .

For this command *peer network login < username >* replace < username > with *jim* and use this password *6avZQLwcUe9b* .

As for the error instead of *make membersrvc* try *membersrvc* and don't wait for an output just open another terminal and type *peer*.
If that doesn't work go to *fabric/build/bin* folder and type *make membersrvc* there.

(Inform me if that worked)